# how to get the previous 4 sunday's of the current date javascript

Tags: javascript, html, date

I want to user JavaScript to generate the previous four Sundays from the current date.
For example, if current date is 
**2018-3-1**, I want to get 2018-2-25, 2018-2-18, 2018-2-11, 2018-2-4.

I have this code but it only gave me the previous Sunday of the current date.
How can I get the previous four Sundays?

```js
var dt = new Date();
var currentWeekDay = dt.getDay();
var lessDays = currentWeekDay == 0 ? 6 : currentWeekDay - 0;
var sunday = new Date(new Date(dt).setDate(dt.getDate() -
  lessDays));

console.log(sunday);
```

Comment: If you're able to use Node, it would be worth taking a look at https://momentjs.com/docs/

Comment: You can use momentjs without Node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea is to use a [loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration). Feed the returned Sunday back into the loop.
Below, I store the returned dates in an array.

```js
var date = new Date();
var loop_count = 4;
var days = [];
var prev_sunday;
var loop_index;

function getPreviousSunday(date) {
  return new Date(
    new Date(date).setDate(
      date.getDate() - (date.getDay() || 7)
    )
  );
}

for (loop_index = 1; loop_index <= loop_count; loop_index++) {
  prev_sunday = getPreviousSunday(prev_sunday || date);
  days.push(prev_sunday);
}

console.log(date);
console.log(days);
```

Comment: Note that this modifies the passed-in Date. And `day_of_week == 0 ? 7 : day_of_week` can be `date.getDay() || 7`. ;-)

Comment: @RobG Thank you. I've modified the code to address your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it that allows for you to adjust which day as well as the frequency of days in the past to look.

```
function findPreviousDay(oDate, day, occurence){
 var weekday = [];
 var prevDays = [];

 weekday.sunday = 0;
 weekday.monday = 1;
 weekday.tuesday = 2;
 weekday.wednesday = 3;
 weekday.thursday = 4;
 weekday.friday = 5;
 weekday.saturday = 6;

 for(i=0;i<occurence;i++){
  prevDay = new Date(oDate).setDate(oDate.getDate()-oDate.getDay()+weekday[day.toLowerCase()]-i*7);
  prevDays.push(new Date(prevDay));
 }

 return prevDays;
}

var d = new Date("3/1/2018");

listOfDays = findPreviousDay(d, "sunday",4);

listOfDays.forEach(function(day){
    document.write(day+"<br/>");
});
```

[Try it out!](https://jsfiddle.net/DanielGale/q514e0nn/)